# Specify to use volatile table in query

Tags: sql, teradata

I created a volatile table with the same name as a table in one of our databases. When I run a query specifying only the table name I'm getting the following error: Table/view/trigger name '...' is ambiguous.

Giving the volatile table a different name solves this issue, but I'm curious if there is a way to specify in a query to use the volatile table. I think that if I specify the database name the DB engine knows that it has to pick the materialized table. Is there "database name" for volatile tables?

Comment: Yep, it's very confusing, this is the main reason why there should be a naming convention for Volatile Tables, e.g. `VT_....` or `#...` :-)

Comment: You can use # in a table name? All these years of using Teradata, I never knew that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [fully-qualified name of the database object](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/get-fully-qualified-name-using-sql-function.aspx) in your query which will prevent problems and confusion

Comment: You should add that the Fully Qualified Name of a Volatile Table includes the username, e.g. `myuser.myvolatiletable`